# How to extract API and DB calls from Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-room

I'm very new on Android world. After developing a beautiful Rest API I thought Android development will be easy, but I'm stuck on basics.

On my Android app, I created Login, that makes an API call, that return a token when valid credentials are provided; this token is stored on shared preferences, and user is redirected to the principal activity: HomeActivity.

This Activity has a lot of work to do:

- It has a BottomNavigationBar, so when the user clicks on a button of it, a new Fragment will be loaded.
- Call to the API endpoint to get resources and show it depending on the fragment.
- Store API response on Database to avoid overload server.

Surely, for Android developer this will be quite easy, but for my is like this:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.ibosca.thub.database.AppDatabase;
import com.ibosca.thub.helpers.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.Channel;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.Content;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.ContentList;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.Town;
import com.ibosca.thub.models.User;
import com.ibosca.thub.parser.ContentParser;
import com.ibosca.thub.volley.MySingleton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String userToken;
public TextView contentList;
private ContentParser contentParser = new ContentParser();
public static AppDatabase db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "townhub").build();

    contentList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentList);
    loadContents();

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    userToken = sharedPref.getString("token", null);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

    View contentsButton = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_contents);
    contentsButton.performClick();

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UNDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_towns:
                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Towns", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_channels:
                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Channels", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_contents:
                            loadContents();
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_question:
                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Questions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            break;

                        case R.id.action_user:
                            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            break;

                    }

                    toast.show();
                    return true;
                }


            });

}

public void ExecuteInsert(ContentList...lists){
    new InsertContents().execute(lists);
}

protected void loadContents() {

    String url = MySingleton.BASE_URL + "/contents";


    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ContentList list = contentParser.fromContents(response);
                        ContentList[] lists = new ContentList[1];
                        lists[0] = list;
                        ExecuteInsert(lists);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + userToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}


public static class InsertContents extends AsyncTask<ContentList, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //Perform pre-adding operation here.
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ContentList...lists) {
        ContentList list = lists[0];

        //Insert towns, channels
        db.townDao().insertArrayList(list.getTowns());
        db.channelDao().insertArrayList(list.getChannels());
        db.userDao().insertArrayList(list.getUsers());
        db.contentDao().insertArrayList(list.getContents());

        //Select data from DB
        List<Town> towns = db.townDao().getAll();
        List<Channel> channels = db.channelDao().getAll();
        List<User> users = db.userDao().getAll();
        List<Content> contents = db.contentDao().getAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
            Content content = contents.get(i);
            Town contentTown = db.townDao().findById(content.getTownId());
            Log.i("Poble: ", contentTown.getName());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        //To after addition operation here.
    }
}
}
```

For a quick summary, on method `loadContents()` I'm making the API call; and the class `InsertContents` it's where I play with local database.

**Finally, the questions:**

1) As you can see, I'm using Volley to make API calls. Are there any best practice to put any "api endpoint" on a separated class, and use this class from the Activity? How to separate this code on Android development?

2) Same for Database management. How can I put the code on a separated class and call it from the Activity? This is currently accomplished, but... I'm unable to update my TextView from the AsyncTask (Update the TextView it's only a easy try, my final goal it's to use a ListView or ReciclerView.

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Comment: I suggest that you look at Retrofit. This is a library that can turn your REST API into a Java API.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [Repository](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006) pattern.

The idea is more or less as follows, lets say you have a `Car` domain class and you database or api interactions perform tipical CRUD operation like, insert a car, retrieve a list of al card or one by its plate number.

You could create an interface like

```
public interface CarRepository {
     void insertCar(@NonNull Car car);

     List<Car> getAllCars();

     Car getCarByPlate(@NonNull String plateNumber);
}
```

Then you can create concrete implementations of said interface depending of which source are you using for storing your data.

For example if using volley you could create a `RestCarRepository` that extends `CarRepository` and fetch/ store data from a rest api using Volley. Or a `DBCarRepository` that uses SQLite (or any other database engine).

Finally you can declare your repository in you activity so you abstract the logic of fetching data.

Disclaimer: There are lots of articles regarding repository pattern (as the posted at the beggining of the answer) and this answer could become more complex when adding more patterns as DI or MVP, this is so you have a grasp of the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for both cases: It would be better separate the view (activity/fragment) from the model or data. You are mixing everything in the activity and in this small case could be ok but if your app grows will be dificult to read and understand and cause problems with the activity/fragment lifecycle.

There are a lot of different aproaches to separate concerns in android in order to do a cleaner code.

I recommend you this repo talking about clean architecture in android apps https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

Also Google has a relatively new library to implements several patterns

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Here you have some help about databases, paging, viewmodel, etc.

**EDIT:**
Answering more in detail:
1) You can follow the Model View Presenter (MVP) pattern considering the activity/fragment like only a View (a component with an only one responsibility, render components) and creating a class (the Presenter) who has the knowledge of the model/data (your api calls) and act like a bridge between View and Model.
The view will delegate in Presenter the calls to the model (for example if some button is pressed) and the Presenter will return the data to the View and the View will have only the way of paint the screen.

2) You can follow the same approach calling the Presenter in order to retrieve the information and painting the data in a RecyclerView.
You can use a ThreadPoolExecutor in order to decouple the data from the activity.